# Как проигнорировать фигурные скобки в функции string.Format

Tags: c#, .net, строки, format

Как проигнорировать фигурные скобки в функции string.Format?
Пример:

```
string.Format("{Name:{0}}", "Value");
```

В результате выполнения данного кода мы получим исключение

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct
>   format.

Что нужно сделать, для того, чтобы избавится от ошибки и получить в результате строку:

```
{Name:Value}
```

Comment: Все-таки не дубликат, хоть и похож. Интерполяция и составное форматирование - все же разные вещи.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Открытие и закрытие скобок интерпретируется как начальный и конечный элемент для функции форматирования строки. Для того чтобы вывести фигурную скобку в строке нужно ее продублировать `{{` для открытия скобки и `}}` для ее закрытия. Исправленный вариант будет выглядеть следущим образом:

```
string.Format("{{Name:{0}}}", "Value");
```

Детали можно посмотреть на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx), а также [тут](http://mirsovetov.net/format-curly-brackets.html)